# How to speedup DataFrame.loc?

Tags: pandas

I have this code where I want to center ratings given by users:

```
for u in users:
    watched.loc[watched.user_id == u, 'rating'] -= watched.loc[watched.user_id == u, 'rating'].mean()
```

I have about 2000 users for a total of 200000 ratings. The code above takes about 20 secs.

If I try

```
watched.set_index('user_id', inplace=True)
```

then I have the error

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop + filtering is a very slow approach; The canonical approach in pandas is group by the variable you want to split by and calculate the average for each group and then update in a single vectorized fashion; To keep the length, you can use `groupby.transform` to calculate the `mean` by `user_id` and then subtract from `rating` column:

```
watched.rating -= watched.rating.groupby(watched.user_id).transform('mean')
```

Comment: Wow it takes 20 ms now! Thank you!